# Creating a full site package

Tags: 7, theming

I found that the [ST Conch](http://drupal.org/project/conch) theme has a full site installation package with that theme.

How do I go about doing this? And would it be possible to populate the database with the data as well...?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *full site package*? What do you mean by *full site installation package*?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It seems it's only a theme. But you are right there are also installation packages available. With what data you want to populate your database with? It sure depends on you that what are you going to do about this.

Answer (score 3):

What you are wanting to create is a Drupal Installation Profile. This is a method of packaging together multiple Drupal contributed modules and/or themes, plus potentially custom code and functionality, into a neat package that can be distributed and installed with the same resulting "full" website every time.

You'll want to refer to the drupal.org documentation on [building installation profiles](http://drupal.org/node/1022020) to get the basics behind how this is done.

Also very helpful will be the [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module. Features allows you to easily package together different sets of Drupal configurations, such as content types, views, and system variables. There are many different documentation and tutorial resources for Features. This is a good [video tutorial on the basic concepts](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DxRBEaD9JCA) of Features.

There are a lot of additional [extensions for Features](http://drupal.org/project/modules?filters=tid%3A11478%20bs_project_sandbox%3A%5B%2A%20TO%20%2A%5D&solrsort=sis_project_release_usage%20desc) that will help you package additional items into a Feature, such as node content, taxonomy terms, theme settings, etc.

In addition, some of the work you want to do in your installation profile (re: "populate the database with the data as well...") may need to be executed within custom code - either a custom module or as part of your installation profile's [install tasks](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_install_tasks/7) and/or [install script](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_install/7). You can even set up a form to allow users to choose from a set of options during the installation.